# Fill Text Forms AND Clickable text forms In C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form application I have a button that opens the SaveFileFrom dialog

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SaveFileDialog savefileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
  savefileDialog1.ShowDialog();
}
```

I was wondering how I could put the file that is chosen in a text box even like so

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

UPDATE* Ok, well since the user might want to open more than one file to save I wanted to take off my button SaveFileFrom and instead make the textbox run through the OpenFileDialog when clicked.
Also, is their a way to make a text link instead of a button?
Like I want a text link to add another text box/

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SaveFileDialog savefileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
  if (savefileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    textBox1.Text = savefileDialog1.Filename;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The filename selected will be saved in SaveFileDialog.FileName

example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

SaveFileDialog SvDlg = new SaveFileDialog();

  if (SvDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
      textBox1.Text = SvDlg.FileName;
  }
  else 
  {
      MessageBox.Show("No file selected.");
  }

}
```